# Generating a random string of 6 characters long in Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

I am learning Python, so pardon me if this is the very crude approach.
I am trying to generate a random string using alphanumeric characters.
Following is my code:

```
#Generating random 6 character string from list 'range'.
def code():
    # List of characters [a-zA-Z0-9]
    chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    code = ''
    for i in range(6):
        n = random.randint(0,61)    # random index to select element.
        code = code + chars[n]      # 6-character string.
    return code
```

What I am trying to do is pick six random elements from the list of characters and append them.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: Check out this link. [\[Is there a Python Library that contains a list of all the ascii characters?\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891453/601770)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Simplicity + improvements:***

- `chars` list. Instead of hardcoding all *lowercase*, *uppercase* and *digit* chars - [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module provides a convenient constants **`string.ascii_letters`** and **`string.digits`**
- `random.randint(0,61)`. Instead of generating random index for further search on `chars` sequence - [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choice) already allows getting a random element from a specified sequence
- `for ...` loop is easily replaced with [*generator* expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

---

The final version:

```
import random
import string


def random_alnum(size=6):
    """Generate random 6 character alphanumeric string"""
    # List of characters [a-zA-Z0-9]
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    code = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    return code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(random_alnum())
    print(random_alnum())
    print(random_alnum())
```

Sample output:

```
g7CZ2G
bczX5e
KPS7vt
```

Comment: You can make `chars` a global, return `code` directly and change the `i` loop variable to `_`, which is an unofficial sign for "i'm not using this name" This is the best answer so far regardless, though. +1

Comment: Since this is python 3.6, you can remove the for loop by using [`''.join(random.choices(chars, k=6))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really is an improvement over my code. I will keep the question open for more idea.

Comment: Also, using the `secrets` module is smart because it uses the best RNG on the system (`random.SystemRandom` if it's available, otherwise a weaker RNG).

Comment: @GregSchmit Depends if you need a cryptographically secure RNG or not.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica In my experience, every time someone asks how to generate random characters for a string, it's because that string will be used as some kind of secret.

Answer (score 5):

Python's [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) library has predefined constants for ASCII letters and digits. So after `import string`, `chars` could be expressed as `chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits`. `chars` could also become a module-level constant, since it does not change in `code()`. According to [PEP8, the official Style Guide for Python code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants), the name would then become `CHARS`.

The `random` module also features `random.choice` and `random.choices` (versions later than Python 3.6), which either draw a single or a given number of samples from a sequence, in your case `chars`. You could then do

```
code = "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(6))
```

or

```
code = "".join(random.choices(chars, k=6))
```

depending on what is available to you.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of modules. I wasn't aware of those.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string for `chars` to avoid the hassle of all the quotes and commas.